# Calling Model->Method() within blade templates

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I asked this on the Laravel 4.x forum and tried to find the answer on Google without any luck.

I'm using Eloquent to load a bunch of user objects that have a `created_at` property. The default MySQL timestamp isn't very readable, so I thought it would be neat to add a `readableDate()` method to my User model which would output the value as "1 minute ago", "2 days ago" instead.

When I call on the method in my blade templates like: `$user->readableDate()` I get the desired output but my whole layout is broken.

Is it, or should it be possible to call on a model method from within a template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Laravel's Eloquent models, you do not need to add custom methods for handling dates. By default, date fields such as `created_at` and `updated_at` are handled as a [Carbon objects](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), which allows you to display the date in a human readable format:

```
{{ $user->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
```

You can add additional [date fields](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#date-mutators) to your Eloquent model with the `getDates()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, blade is compiled to PHP. :)

You just have to:

Pass your user to your view:

```
 return View::make('showUser')->with('user', $user);
```

And then use it:

```
<hml><body>

    Last update: {{ $user->readableDate() }}

</body></hml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume you are wrapping it inside blade tags {{ code here }}, or did you miss that part?

Also, your model should be called using the static approach like this:

```
{{ User::readableDate() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured this out. What I was trying to do is possible but it was throwing an error that I couldn't see. When I viewed the source of the page the usual laravel error HTML was below my output. The error was being thrown by default values in the created_at field.